How to simulate Xilinx IP-cores in Modelsim?
I have Vivado 2016.4 and Modelsim 2021.3 installed. My Vivado project contains Xilinx ip-cores. I want to model everything in Modelsim. It is useless to choose the Modelsim simulator in the simulation settings, because it takes a VERY long time to load this way. I usually create .do-files for Modelsim and so build the project. In this case, it is not possible to do so simply, because ip-cores are used. How do I compile these ip cores and use them in Modelsim? And then write something like "vcom -work fifo_generator D:/Xilinx /.../fifo_generator.vhd" and that's it? Is this even possible?
I found some scraps of information about unisim and compxlib on the Internet, but I don't have anything like that. I don't understand how to run it all :(

A simulation netlist is created during IP Catalog run (when the core is generated).
The directory tree location of the simulation netlist varies with the tool version, a good place to look for the simulation netlist is:
<ip_name>/<ip_name>_sim_netlist.v
If you can't find it (Linux), start in the generated ip_name folder and do:
find . -iname '*sim_netlist.*'
That should find it.
The simulation netlist contains instances of Xilinx primitives (simprim and unisim libraries), which are specific to the particular version of tool you are using and the part targeted, so you will probably need to compile them and put the compiled libraries on the simulators search path.
Compxlib is the tool used to compile the libraries.  Its a Xilinx tool.  There are different ways to run it search 'How to compile Vivado simulation libraries for third party simulators?' to get information on how to compile the libs.  Also see here: how to compile 3rd party libs for Xilinx
If you are using the Vivado simulator, its knows about simprims and unisims library components. For 3rd party simulators (ex. Modelsim) you must compile the libraries then set the simulators search path to find them, in order to simulate using the <ip>_simulation_netlist.v file.
There can be unexpected side affects when using the Xilinx simulation model.  One is the behavior of the GSR (global set reset) which is a hidden (somewhat) reset that is actually in the hardware.  Users don't get any choice WRT the use of the GSR, its built in to the model.  It will hold the simulation model in reset a certian amount of time after t=0 in simulation.   You will need to adapt your testbench accordingly.  Search 'Xilinx GSR' for more explanation.

I tried to do what you wrote, but Vivado gave me a lot of errors. I found unisim in the directory "C:\Xilinx16\Vivado\2016.4\data\vhdl\src\unisims " and compiled it in Modelsim. Next, I compiled the *_sim_netlist.vhd files. Now all my files are being compiled, but the simulation is not running. Modelsim does not give any errors, it just freezes at the moment "#Loading work.main_tb(behavioral)#1".

I compiled all the IP cores into the work library. But at the same time, the blocks of my design simply declare the component by the name of the IP core. That is, they expect the IP core to be in the same library as them. But it lies in the "work" library. Is it possible to make the compiler look for these components in other libraries too? At the same time, I still don't understand why no errors are being issued, and the simulation just doesn't load.

Sounds like you are using VHDL.  Modelsim has the concept of 'library mapping' which provides the opportunity for files to be compiled into any physical directory, and specifies the mapping or translation to the logical name which appears in VHDL.  I think the tcl command for thisi is vmap, and there is a way to do it thru menus.  A basic Modelsim tutorial would walk you thru th

I did it. First, using the 'vlib' command, I created the necessary directories, then using 'vmap' I linked the library names and these directories.
